# Limit $t\to \infty$ of a convolution

Tags: limits, convolution

I would like to expect that, if $h(t)=f(t)\ast g(t)$, ie,

$$h(t)=\int_0^t f(t-t')g(t')dt',$$

and $\lim_{t\to \infty} f(t)=\lim_{t\to \infty} g(t)=0,$ so $\lim_{t\to \infty} h(t)=0$ (or maybe I have at least some other information).

However, I have uncertanties for proceed.

Thank you so much.

Comment: That convolution will not exist with just those assumption.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven is it ask a lot if I ask you a counterexample...? Thank you so much and sorry "for abuse".

Comment: First of all, this is not what is usually called convolution. Next, note that we can rewrite $h$ as $$h(t)=g(t) \int_0^t f(s)ds.$$ Pick $f(s)=1$ for $s<1$ and $f(s)=1/s$ otherwise, and pick $g(s)=1/\ln(s)$, then $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} h(t)=\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1+\ln(s)}{\ln(s)}=1$. So you can get any limit you like (and also make it diverge).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, oh, sorry please, it had a typo, it may be $h(t)=\int_0^t f(t-t')g(t')dt'$. Thank you.

Comment: Even if you change it this way, it will not work. Pick $f(s)=1/\sqrt{s}=g(s)$. Then we get $$h(t)=\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}\sqrt{x}} dx.$$ So $h$ does not depend on $t$ and is different from zero. Again, you can change the scaling and make it diverge if you like.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Perfect, is always $\pi$. Please, if you want post as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the comments it is not true. A counterexample would be with $f(s)=1/\sqrt{s}=g(s)$. Then we get
$$ h(t)=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}\sqrt{x}} dx = \pi.$$
Thus, $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} h(t)=\pi \neq 0$. With a different power, $f(s)=s^{-1/4}=g(s)$ we get that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} h(t)=\infty$. Indeed, we have in this case
$$ h(t) = \int_0^t \frac{1}{(t-s)^{1/4}} \frac{1}{s^{1/4}} ds
= \int_0^t \frac{1}{t^{1/4}}\frac{1}{(1-s/t)^{1/4}} \frac{1}{s^{1/4}} ds
\stackrel{x=s/t, ds=tdx}{=} t^{3/4} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1-x)^{1/4} x^{1/4}} dx.   $$